# how to push a new key value pair in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

Hi I want to push a new key value pair an existing in TypeScript, I tried below step but nothing happening and no error please help

```
 profile = {"RouteID":"B76F77922EF83A4EE04024921F591A6F","Name":"3019998FALCON","rName":"KILGORE REMOVED"}

let newvalue = "jzket"
profile["userID"] = newvalue
```

Comment: The only possible error I see is the missing `let` keyword before the `profile` var and some missing semicolons. The rest of the code seems OK to me... please consider to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if possible in order to reproduce the possible error. This way, it's more likely volunteers on SO can help you.

Comment: Also be sure to write what you were expecting to happen. After the fixes, the above code is valid TypeScript, so what do you mean by "nothing happening" -- what did you expect to happen? And what do you mean by "no error" -- what kind of error did you expect?

Comment: it works fine. I just added `var` before profile. I am using Typescript 2.5.3 maybe it is about the version.

Comment: it works, thanks a lot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code in your question is largely correct, here is a full working example:

```
const profile = {
    "RouteID": "B76F77922EF83A4EE04024921F591A6F",
    "Name": "3019998FALCON",
    "rName": "KILGORE REMOVED"
}

profile["userID"] = "jzket";

// Works everywhere
console.log(profile["userID"]);

// Works, but violates the type information available here
console.log(profile.userID);
```

You'll notice that the type system will complain about the latter usage, because `userID` isn't part of the type inferred for `profile`.

You can either stick with the first example (`profile['userID']`) or provide a bit more type information:

```
interface Profile {
    RouteID: string;
    Name: string;
    rName: string;
    userID?: string;
}

const profile: Profile = {
    "RouteID": "B76F77922EF83A4EE04024921F591A6F",
    "Name": "3019998FALCON",
    "rName": "KILGORE REMOVED"
}

profile["userID"] = "jzket";

// Works everywhere
console.log(profile["userID"]);

// Works, but violates the type information available here
console.log(profile.userID);
```

Answer (score 3):

I totally agree with @Fenton. Maybe a little bit better approach is to add a new *key* / *value* pair with:

`Object.assign` like this:

```
const newProfile = Object.assign(profile, { userID: "jzket" });
```

Or with `Spread Syntax`:

```
const newProfile = ({...profile, userID: "jzket" });
```

**JSFiddle** example:

```js
const profile = {
  "ruteID":"B76F77922EF83A4EE04024921F591A6F",
  "Name":"3019998FALCON",
  "rName":"KILGORE REMOVED",
};

// With object assign
const exampleOne = Object.assign(profile, { userID: "jzket" });

// With spread syntax
const exampleTwo = ({...profile, userID: "jzket" })

console.log(exampleOne);
console.log(exampleTwo);
```

Useful links:

[Spread Syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

[Object Assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)